# Problem with playing videos from OneDrive in my HTML page using AzureMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, onedrive, azure-media-player

When I get an embedded link from a video on my OneDrive and use the link to show the video (changing the embedded to download in the link), everything seems to be okay. the video gets played and works fine, although when I run the same code the day after I get this error on my player:The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support 504000000

I don't know exactly what I'm doing every time, but the problem gets fixed when I open my OneDrive application.

Is it related to an active session on my Azure or OneDrive or anything related to expiration time?

Code to play the video:

```
<div>
        <video id="videoPlayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" controls width="640" height="400" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "html5FairPlayHLS","silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
            <source src=@Model.Report.VideoSource type="video/mp4" />
            <p class="amp-no-js">
                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
            </p>
        </video>
    </div>
```

- I'm using azure media player
- I set a specific expiration time for the video but I still have the same problem.

Any ideas how to solve this?